# How can I change this code so that it will stop looping but display the same thing?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to code my program so that when the array compartment entered is occupied , it will tell the user which compartments is empty . However , I have no idea how to change the code so that it will stop looping yet display the same things . This is my code :

```
                for (int i = 0; i < compartmentno.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (compartmentno[i] == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Available compartments are" + (i + 1).ToString());
                    }
                }
```

How do I make it so that the program just shows a messagebox with all the available compartments instead of showing 10 messagebox ? Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ for it:

```
int availableCompartments = compartmentno.Count(x=> x == 0);

MessageBox.Show("Available compartments are:" + availableCompartments.ToString());
```

[WORKING FIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YNDFIV)

Here is with Apartment Numbers :

```
public static void Main()
{

  int [] compartmentNo = { 1,3,5,6,7,8,9,0,4,0};


  var availableCompartments = compartmentNo
                             .Select((value, index) => new {index, value})
                             .Where(x=> x.value == 0)
                             .Select(x=>x.index);

  int Count = availableCompartments.Count();

  string Values = String.Join(",",availableCompartments);

  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("No of Aparments : {0} and aprtments No : {1}",Count,Values));


}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YkO0T2)

Comment: This won't tell you which compartments are available, just how many there are

Comment: That's just the count not the apartment

Comment: @Greg added numbers as well

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the compartments in one string and show message outside of the loop.

```
using System.Text;

StringBuilder compartments = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < compartmentno.Length; )
                {
                    if (compartmentno[i] == 0)
                    {
                        compartments.Append(++i.ToString() + ", ");

                    }
                }

MessageBox.Show("Available compartments are" + compartments.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int availableCompartments = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < compartmentno.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (compartmentno[i] == 0)
                    {
                        availableCompartments++;
                    }
                }
MessageBox.Show("Available compartments are " + availableCompartments.ToString());
```

Note that this will only show you how many compartments are available, not which ones.

Comment: Is there a code to show which compartments(ex:1-10) are available too ?

Comment: What information do you have about each compartment? It's not apparent from your code. You would probably be better to create a list of objects of type compartment that have several properties like isAvailable, name... then you could easily return the name of each one that is available.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** You have to use same loop for this but instead of showing message every time you can show it once after manipulation.

Use following code:

```
int avli = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < compartmentno.Length; i++)
{
    if (compartmentno[i] == 0)
    {
        avli++;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show("Available compartments are" + avli.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for that.

```
var avaiableItems= string.Join(",", compartmentno.Where(x => x == 0).Select((item, index) => index+1));
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Available compartments are {0}",avaiableItems));
```

Comment: snap! but it looks like you got in first

Comment: That happens here.. no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in one line of code with this. :)

It uses the not so known about indexer of the Linq Select statement

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Available compartments are {0}", String.Join(", ", compartmentno.Select((s, i) => new {i, s}).Where(p=>p.s == 0).Select(p=>p.i +1))));
```